# How do I force the pointer icon to 'grab', override underlying cursor styles while panning?

Tags: html, css

When I set the css of the container to 'grab' I see that it changes, but most of the viewport contains divs with pointer 'hand', which override it.
I want to give the impression that the grab is strictly for panning the contents of the viewport and nothing else.
Some ideas:

1. use !important (but Javascript css doesn't support that).
2. Use an invisible or 0 opacity div for panning mode (I am going to try this
   one.
3. Something better that is commonly used that I don't know about
   yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating a jsFiddle by modifying one that I found which was doing something similar.

```
var scale = 1.0;

var drag = {
  elem: null,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  state: false
};
var delta = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};


$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  if (!drag.state) {
    let $workspace = $('#workspace');
    let $workspaceContents = $('.workspace_contents');
    $('#pan-screen').css({
      width: $workspaceContents.width,
      height: $workspaceContents.height
    });

    drag.elem = $('.workspace-contents');
    drag.x = e.pageX;
    drag.y = e.pageY;
    drag.state = true;
  }
  return false;
});


$(document).mousemove(function(e) {


  if (drag.state) {
    delta.x = e.pageX - drag.x;
    delta.y = e.pageY - drag.y;

    var cur_offset = $(drag.elem).offset();

    $(drag.elem).offset({
      left: (cur_offset.left + delta.x),
      top: (cur_offset.top + delta.y)
    });

    drag.x = e.pageX;
    drag.y = e.pageY;
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  if (drag.state) {
    drag.state = false;
  }
});
```

solution fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/davidjmcclelland/t51b96em/27/